# Formula to use current value of a cell, which won't update in the future

Tags: excel, cell, return-value

Is there any function to use a current value of a cell, which won't update in the future if I change the value of the target cell?

For example:
A1 = 5

A3 = A1 (which equals 5)

now, when I change the value of A1 to 6
A4 = A1 (should equals 6, but the A3 should remain 5)

Is that even possible in Excel?

Comment: From what I am reading you are asking to be able to edit the value of the cell but not change the actual value in a different formula. I am sure there would be a way of doing this in VBA but that would kind of defeat the purpose of a spreadsheet and would cause problems with other formulas later.  Personally I would suggest a column with old values, and then one with new values, especially if you are doing comparative values.

Comment: Hi @VanCowboy, thank you for your reply. I'm trying to create simple invoicing spreadsheet so today my services are at £10, and f.e. tomorrow will be £12. So I want to use the cell defining current price for my services, but seems to be impossible easy way in excel. Looks like the only way is to create separate references for each price change. Am I correct?

Comment: I would, especially if you are trying to reference a price for one time versus another.  2 separate columns... Original Price, Current Price.

Comment: you can date stamp each rate. Have a begin date and an end date associated with each rate. Then whenever a service is rendered you can use the date that service was rendered to look up the date range in your rates table and return the applicable rate.

Comment: @Brad Hi Brad, great suggestion, will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Say we start with **A1** and **A4** both empty.  The following Event macro will allow you to enter a value in **A1** and have it appear in **A4**.  Each time the value in **A1** is changed, then new value will be copied into the first empty cell below **A4.**

Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range, A4 As Range, N As Long
    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    Set A4 = Range("A4")
    If Intersect(A1, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If A4.Value = "" Then
            A4.Value = A1.Value
        Else
            N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Cells(N, "A").Value = A1.Value
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**